# What could cause NSMigrationManager to return a nil error?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, foundation

I have this code:

```
NSError *error; // NSMigrationManager hates it if you don't provide an error pointer
BOOL result = [manager migrateStoreFromURL:sStoreURL
                                      type:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                   options:nil
                          withMappingModel:mappingModel
                          toDestinationURL:dStoreURL
                           destinationType:NSBinaryStoreType
                        destinationOptions:nil
                                     error:&error];
```

To my surprise, it's sometimes returning NO and leaving/setting the `error` pointer to nil. What can cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused if you have a custom migration policy that returns `NO` without setting the `error` pointer. e.g.

```
- (BOOL)createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:(NSManagedObject *)sInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(SVMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError **)error;
{
    return NO;
}
```

Check the code carefully to find any situations where this could occur.